# how to set jcheckbox inside jtable dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, defaulttablemodel

In this picture the return table head values show in the checkbox .

here jtable  the values from database

I tried it but classcastexception occured because of boolean value cast to string

i don't know why that error occured

[image]

this is my code

```
    static Object[][] data;
String[] colName = {"Book", "Member", "Issue Date", "Return Date ",
        "Remark","Return" };

List<Issue>issues=ServiceFactory.getIssueServiceImpl().findAllIssue();
data=new Object[issues.size()][6];


for(Issue issue:issues){

    data[i][0]=issue.getMemberId().getName();
    data[i][1]=issue.getBookId().getName();
    data[i][2]=issue.getIssueDate();
    data[i][3]=issue.getReturnDate();
    data[i][4]=issue.getRemark();
    data[i][5]=issue.getStatus();

    i++;
}
```

here exception occured

```
 DefaultTableModel  dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, colName);{
     public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
         switch (c) {
           case 0: return Boolean.class;
           default: return String.class;
         }   
       } };
 retunTable = new JTable();
 retunTable.setModel(dtm);
 retunTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);


return retunTable;
```

if u know about this please share answers here...

**edit**

```
      DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, colName);{
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
         switch (c) {
           case 0: return Boolean.class;
           default: return String.class;
         }   
       } };

     dtm .addRow(data); 
 retunTable = new JTable();
 retunTable.setModel(dtm);
 retunTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);


return retunTable;
```

Comment: you will need to implement table cell renderer.

Comment: You should provide custom cell renderer for you JTable. Please have a look at `ColorRenderer` class in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: What does `issue.getStatus()` return?  A `String` or a `boolean`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer issue.getStatus() is a boolean value

Comment: Then your `TableModel`'s `getColumnClass` method is returning the wrong class type for the column...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From you example and code, this looks wrong to me...

```
DefaultTableModel  dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, colName);{
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        switch (c) {
            case 0: return Boolean.class;
            default: return String.class;
        }   
    } 
};
```

Isn't column `0` "Book" ... or more importantanly, `issue.getMemberId().getName()`

Shouldn't it be...

```
DefaultTableModel  dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, colName);{
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return c == 5 ? Boolean.class : String.class
    } 
};
```

Where column 5 is "Return"?

Answer (score 3):

What you need is to use a cell editor for your JTable's cell. You can use DefaultCellEditor for your column and use the constructor that takes JTextField as input param.

for example, if your table's 2nd column needs to be a text field then you can do something like this:

```
TableColumn col2 = returnTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
col2.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField()));
```

For a detailed explanation [See Oracle's tutorial for Table cell Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor)

Hope this helps.